# Disable google AdSense on Mobile Devices using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adsense

I want to disable Google ADS in Mobile devices.

At the minutes I have this

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
}else
{
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="*****"
     data-ad-slot="****"
     data-ad-format="***"></ins>
}
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

But it’s not working.

I’m struggling to find the code to disable Google ADS in Mobile devices.

Any help or other ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work with some syntax changes,

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
isMobile = false;
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 isMobile = true;
}
if(isMobile){
  $(".adsbygoogle").hide();
}else{
$(".adsbygoogle").show();
}
</script>

<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Your html,

```
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block"
         data-ad-client="*****"
         data-ad-slot="****"
         data-ad-format="***"></ins>
```

Give it a try, this should work.